# How do you get random RGB in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, rgb

I have this code that uses RGB color selection and I was wondering how to make JavaScript do a random color using the RGB method and remember it throughout the code.

EDIT: I tried this:

```
var RGBColor1 = (Math.round, Math.random, 255)
var RGBColor2 = (Math.round, Math.random, 255)
var RGBColor3 = (Math.round, Math.random, 255)
```

but it doesn't work. Help please!

EDIT 2: The code uses this:

```
g.fillStyle="rgba(R,G,B,0.2)";
g.strokeStyle="rgba(R,G,B,0.3)";
E();
```

The letters represent the color of RGB.

EDIT 3: The doubles of this question are using HEX values, not RGB values.

Comment: Generate three random numbers (in the range of 0 to 255), insert them into a string (format `"rgb(n1, n2, n3)"`) and assign that to a variable. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
function random_rgba() {
    var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
    return 'rgba(' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')';
}

var color = random_rgba();

g.fillStyle   = color;
g.strokeStyle = color;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GP3z8/2/)

Comment: This is the first one to work for me but the color of the stroke and fill are different colors.

Comment: @ipodlover3354 - I thought that was the point, but I've updated the answer to use the same color for both.

Answer (score 32):

```js
const randomBetween = (min, max) => min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
const r = randomBetween(0, 255);
const g = randomBetween(0, 255);
const b = randomBetween(0, 255);
const rgb = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`; // Collect all to a css color string
```

Comment: Appreciate it! The easiest to read out of them all

Answer (score 23):

Here's a very simple method that works off of a single random number generation. Basically, it generates a number between `0` and `0xfffff` (or `2^24`, the highest number you can get from 24 bits). The highest value you can get from 8 bits is `255`. This algorithm takes the left-most 8 bits of the random number for RED, the middle 8 bits for GREEN, and the last 8 bits for BLUE, using all 24 bits of the random number.

```js
function getRandomRgb() {
  var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
  var r = num >> 16;
  var g = num >> 8 & 255;
  var b = num & 255;
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(getRandomRgb());
}
```

Console output (sample):

```
rgb(2, 71, 181)
rgb(193, 253, 111)
rgb(172, 127, 203)
rgb(203, 53, 175)
rgb(226, 45, 44)
rgb(102, 181, 19)
rgb(92, 165, 221)
rgb(250, 40, 162)
rgb(250, 252, 120)
rgb(67, 59, 246)
```

Adapted from [source](http://develobert.blogspot.com/2008/06/random-color-generation-with-javascript.html).

Comment: Somewhere you will need `var randomRgb = getRandomRgb();`. Then use `randomRgb` wherever you need it. I leave how to scope it all to you, since I have no idea how to actually incorporate it into your current code.

Comment: +1 for doing just one random number generation.

Comment: Agreed; it's beautiful: but *I have no idea how it works..!*